# why the celery worker take so much memory useage

Tags: python-3.x

Now I am using celery `5.1.2` and Python 3.9 to run some task concurrency, this is my start script:

```
    export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8 \
    && export LANG=en_US.utf-8 \
    && nohup celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker \
    --loglevel=INFO -n worker2 -Q non_editor_pick_and_diff_pull --concurrency 2 > /dev/null &

    export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8 \
    && export LANG=en_US.utf-8 \
    && nohup celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker \
    --loglevel=INFO -n worker3 -Q non_editor_pick_and_non_diff_pull --concurrency 3 > /dev/null &
```

to my surprise, the celery worker take 100MB+ for each worker, why the celery take so much RAM memory? Is it possible to make the memory lower,10MB or less? I just run a function in the celery task, really need 100MB? This is the top command output:

```
24073 root      25   5  677220 139988   4456 S  0.0  7.4  22:14.10 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker2 -Q non_editor_pick_and_diff_pull --concurrency 2              
24076 root      25   5  677024 139744   4412 S  0.0  7.4  22:11.04 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker2 -Q non_editor_pick_and_diff_pull --concurrency 2              
24078 root      25   5  676848 134760   3848 S  0.0  7.2  93:01.93 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker3 -Q non_editor_pick_and_non_diff_pull --concurrency 3          
24072 root      25   5  675332 133964   4560 S  7.3  7.1 173:10.84 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker3 -Q non_editor_pick_and_non_diff_pull --concurrency 3          
24075 root      25   5  670876 128804   3860 S  0.0  6.8 129:24.36 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker3 -Q non_editor_pick_and_non_diff_pull --concurrency 3          
24071 root      25   5  655128 123692   4132 S  0.0  6.6  13:17.96 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker1 -Q editor_pick_and_diff_pull --concurrency 2                  
24074 root      25   5  646624 120068   4272 S  0.0  6.4  13:04.01 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker1 -Q editor_pick_and_diff_pull --concurrency 2                  
24000 root      25   5  624856  98748   2728 S  0.0  5.2   9:41.82 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker1 -Q editor_pick_and_diff_pull --concurrency 2                  
24001 root      25   5  624868  98724   2716 S  0.0  5.2  12:43.68 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker2 -Q non_editor_pick_and_diff_pull --concurrency 2              
24002 root      25   5  624840  98708   2676 S  1.3  5.2  44:47.66 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker3 -Q non_editor_pick_and_non_diff_pull --concurrency 3          
24005 root      25   5  624696  98060   2412 S  0.0  5.2   7:59.62 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A dolphin.tasks.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker4 -Q cert_expire_check --concurrency 1
```

Comment: I have the same question, hope someone cast some light over this.